# How can I list all questions I asked anonymously on Quora?

Tags: quora

How can I list all questions that I asked anonymously on Quora?

Comment: I guess, you have already seen [this thread](http://www.quora.com/Anonymity-on-Quora/Where-can-I-find-my-anonymous-answers-questions-comments-and-other-activity-e-g-follows-on-Quora), right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no option to do so. Alternatively you can keep track of them using your followed questions

http://www.quora.com/home/following

On a different note, for all new questions the first follower is the person who asked the question.